# What is the Limit Point Property supposed to mean?

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

In analysis we recently learned about the limit point property. This says a subset K of M has the limit point property if every subset L of K s.t. L has infinitely elements, there is an element q of K s.t. q is a limit point of L in M.

I am a little confused about this definition. Is this supposed to be equivalent to compactness? Will a set with the limit point property be closed (i.e. it contains all of its limit points)? I can't imagine any infinite subset of an open ball not containing atleast one limit point in the open ball, but since I am new to analysis I am probably thinking about this in the wrong way. Could someone please clear this definition up for me?

Comment: sorry, typo, I fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the open interval $K=(0,1)$ and take the set $L=\{1/x : x \in \mathbb{Z}^+\}$. This set is infinite but the only limit point it has is $0$ which is outside the set. This implies it does not have the limit point property.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding what a limit point is. If I take 1/2 which is in L, then for any r > 0 doesn't there exist some element 1/x of L where d(1/2, 1/x) < r? making 1/2 a limit point

Comment: @vbcnxm no. For any $r > 0$ includes $r=1/100$ and the interval $1/2 \pm 1/100$ contain no other points in $L$. The closest point is $1/3$ which still leaves $1/2$ very isolated.

Answer (score 0):

This is called [sequential compactness.](https://math.la.asu.edu/%7Ekuiper/371Ch3_extra/371Ch3_extra.pdf) It is equivalent to compactness for [second countable spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-countable_space).